# What do curly braces in XAML actually mean?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm a long-time C# programmer but I'm completely new to WPF and XAML. I can find plenty of tutorials that say "this is how to achieve this specific thing" but not "this is *why* you do this to achieve this specific thing". I'm seriously struggling to understand the meaning of various syntax in XAML.

In this case, **what do curly braces in attributes *actually mean?*** What do they get translated to in terms of code? How do I reason about them? How do they get interpreted? Why does there seem to be multiple syntaxes (`Binding="{Binding someProperty}"` vs `Binding="{Binding path=someProperty}"`)?

I must be missing something obvious, but I've spent literally days reading tutorials, watching tutorials, even fighting my way through the immensely dry and difficult-to-understand [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-overview) and I still can't seem to figure it out.

---

Let me try to illustrate where I'm getting stuck.

For example, say I was given this:

```
int result = SomeUnknownFunction(42, 79);
```

I don't have to know what `SomeUnknownFunction` does to reason about what's happening here. I can say, ok, the first part defines a new variable of type `int`, the second part runs some function with two inputs, and the equals sign assigns the result of that function to the variable.

Now say I was given this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}">
```

I can say, ok, when the XAML parser gets to this bit, the C# code it spits out creates an object instance of type `TextBox`. That class has (or inherits) a property called `Text`, and we're setting it to... uh... some magic syntax inside curly braces...

This is where I'm stuck. I think some part of this is called a "markup extension" (which is the most incredibly generic and meaningless name possible), but I can't even figure out if that means "the curly braces and everything inside" or just "the Binding part". Sometimes there's an equals sign inside the curly braces, sometimes not. What's the difference? The word `Binding` is a... something? Is it a function and we're passing in `Name`, and it returns a new Binding object that is somehow assigned to the `Binding` property?

Comment: It's described right here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0

Comment: @Dai Thanks, but I don't want to know about binding specifically, I want to know about curly brace syntax in general. This is another instance of _"this is how to achieve this specific thing"_ without explaining _why_ that's how to achieve that specific thing. Also why put "in XAML" in the title? That's what tags are for.

Comment: I edited your title because my reading was "what are curly braces in C# for?" which is not what you're asking.

Comment: @Dai Well... no I don't think I really care how the XAML compiler works, I really just want to know what the practical effect of the curly braces is. I want to understand how to reason about the effect. I've edited my question to clarify my confusion. Or just make it a worse question, I'm not sure. I'm struggling here.

Comment: Get a copy of Adam Nathan's WPF Book (WPF Unleashed). It wasn't until I read the first (?) Chapter that I started to really understand XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They say the best way to get a correct answer on the internet is to post an incorrect one, so let's give that a go.

I'll use this as an example:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="Some default text :)"/>
<Label Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=MyTextBox}"/>
```

This binds the `Content` property of the `Label` class to the `Text` property of the `TextBox` class, giving us this result:

[image]

---

### How this works

When the XAML compiler runs, `<Label ... />` will be translated into code that generates an instance of the `Label` class at runtime. We can set properties on that instance from XAML. Normally, when you set a property using the [Attribute syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#attribute-syntax-properties), the string within the double-quotes is exactly what the property will be set to. For instance:

```
<Label Content="Binding Text, ElementName=MyTextBox"/>
```

Since we didn't use curly braces, that string will be taken literally as the value to assign to the `Content` property:

[image]

This is what we've learnt so far:

[image]

If we add the curly braces, now the XAML compiler treats it differently. The word before the first space in the curly braces is now treated as the name of a *Markup Extension*. Markup Extensions are classes inheriting from the `MarkupExtension` class.

In this case, the first part of the text in the curly braces is `Binding`. [By convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/markup-extensions-overview#defining-the-support-type-for-a-custom-markup-extension), Markup Extension classes are usually named with "Extension" on the end, like `BindingExtension`<sup>1</sup>. XAML is smart and allows you to save some typing and be a little less verbose by leaving out the `Extension` part of the class name when typing the name of a Markup Extension in curly braces.

[image]

So now we know what the curly braces and first part of the string inside those curly braces mean, but what about the rest. Why is there *sometimes* an equals sign and sometimes not?

After the text `Binding` there's a space, and the rest of the string is treated as comma-separated inputs to the Markup Extension. How does that work in practice? Well, if the first inputs have no equals sign they'll be passed into the Markup Extension class' constructor as strings.<sup>2</sup>

In our example, the `Binding` class would be created with a parameter value of `Text`. If you have a look at the [source for the `Binding` class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/Binding.cs,211), you can see there's two constructors. The one that takes a string sets the `Path` property to the value of that string:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public Binding() {}
 
        /// <summary>
        /// Convenience constructor.  Sets most fields to default values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">source path </param>
        public Binding(string path)
        {
            if (path != null)
            {
                if (System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();  // This is actually never called since CurrentDispatcher will throw if null.
 
                Path = new PropertyPath(path, (object[])null);
            }
        }
```

[image]

After the class has been instantiated using whatever constructor parameters you supplied, it then treats the remaining equal-sign-separated inputs as key-value pairs. The key is the name of a public property on the Markup Extension and the value is the what that public property is set to.

If you again look at the [`Binding` class' source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/Binding.cs,585), you'll see there's a public property called `ElementName`. In our example, `ElementName` is being set to the literal string value of `MyTextBox`.

[image]

---

### Summary

The curly braces tell the XAML compiler to treat the contents of those curly braces as the name of a class inheriting from `MarkupExtension`, followed by a space, followed by the constructor parameters (if any), followed by key-value pairs that represent the names of public properties and their values.

The property's value will then be calculated by calling the `ProvideValue` method on the class extending `MarkupExtension`.

---

### Notes

<sup>1.</sup> The `Binding` class is an exception to this rule, and is literally just called `Binding` without the "Extension" part.

<sup>2.</sup> I'm not sure what happens if there's no matching constructor.

---

**Disclaimer:** I have absolutely no clue what I'm talking about. Please correct this if it's wrong!

Answer (score 3):

I guess this explains the syntactic meaning of the braces:

> "Markup extensions are a XAML technique for obtaining a value that's
> not a primitive or a specific XAML type. For attribute usage, markup
> extensions use the known character sequence of an opening curly brace
> { to enter the markup extension scope, and a closing curly brace } to
> exit." ([Overview of markup extensions for XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/markup-extensions-overview))

---

> "I think some part of this is called a "markup extension" (which is
> the most incredibly generic and meaningless name possible), but I
> can't even figure out if that means "the curly braces and everything
> inside" or just "the Binding part" "

**An attempt to explain it while keeping it simple**:

XAML is a markup language that is underlying certain semantic rules. Becaise of the very advanced processor, XAML has a dynamic set of tags/objects. Using declared namespaces, the XAML processor is able to map XAML elements to actual C# objects. XAML allows to implement some simple logic using special objects like `Trigger`. But the language, or a markup language in general, is very limited when it comes to complex logic and dynamic values.

Markup languages are static as they require static values. For example in C# you can implement an algorithm based on variables (acting like placeholders for data) that are dynamically calculated during runtime. In markup, all values are provided statically, the moment you compose the markup.
The idea is to use markup extensions to enable dynamic value calculation.

For example, there is no way you could implement a complex and dynamic logic like the WPF binding engine by using markup alone. Data binding is a concept that allows to "inject" dynamic data values into the markup (to put it simple). Data binding is realized by using the concept of markup extensions.

The WPF way to extend the XAML markup functionality is to introduce the concept of markup extensions. From this point of view the name "Markup Extension" is very good. Other markup languages try to achieve something similar by adding more functionality to the processor (extend the language syntax and semantics) or by dynamically modifying/overwriting the actual markup. In comparison markup extensions are more powerful as they truely extend the markup beyond the limitations of the processor. The rules are now dictated by the .NET compiler and not the markup processor.

To implement a markup extension, the object must extend the abstract class `MarkupExtension`. The implementation usually has a constructor and can provide additional public properties. `MarkupExtension` exposes a single abstract method `MarkupExtension.ProvideValue` which is called by the XAML processor in order to obtain the dynamically calculated value, provided by the implementor.
One famous extension is the `Binding` class. `Binding` extends `MarkupExtension` and exposes additional properties like `Source`, `Converter`, `Path` etc.

The syntax expected by the XAML processor is

```
{<markup_extension_class_name> constructor_value, <markup_extension_property>=property_value}
```

Like `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Username, ElementName=MyControl}" />`:

- The processor is processing the markup `<TextBlock`.
- The processor finds the attribute `Text` on the `TextBlock` element and the assigned value (the expression).
- The value's curly braces tell the processor that the content between the opening and closing braces is an object
  that extends `MarkupExtension`.
- The XAML engine will create an instance of this object, in this case the `Binding` class, using
  the constructor parameter `Username` and initializes its property
  `ElementName` with the value `"MyControl"`.
- The XAML engine will then use the constructed instance to call the `MarkupExtension.ProvideValue`
  method to get the dynamically calculated value. In this case the XAML engine will create a `TextBlock` instance and assign the dynamically calculated result of the `Binding` markup extension to the `TextBlock.Text` property

A special rule of the XAML processor is that in case the extension's class name is suffixed with *"Extension"*. The processor would still be able to identify the class even if the actual markup omits the *"Extension"* suffix. For example, if the class is named *BindingExtension* you can simplify the name and write *Binding* in the markup.

By implementing the `Binding` markup extension, the rather simple markup code extents into the highly sophisticated WPF framework to "connect" the binding engine to the XAML language.

Sadly I can't recommend a good source other than the official Microsoft documentation. In addition to the link you have provided in your question or those suggested by other answers, you can read the useful remarks on the [MarkupExtension.ProvideValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.markupextension.providevalue?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#remarks) property and the [MarkupExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.markupextension?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#remarks) class.
I also suggest to implement your own very simple markup extension or to take a look at existing implementations you can find on the net to get the idea. Markup extensions are quite simple to use.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you! I actually wrote my own very long answer (which I _think_ is correct) but due to a long power outage I was unable to post it, and then forgot because it's the weekend. I'm about to post it because I think it explains some concepts in a better way for complete beginners, but I think both answers will be worth reading. WRT the name "Markup Extension", I still think this is a very poor name. Sure, it's an extension to the markup, but it's unclear in what way. It should be called "Dynamic Value" or something more meaningful. "Milk" vs just "Liquid", so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the syntax of a XAML file, you can read all the gory details here

[Markup Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#markup-extensions)

> XAML defines a markup extension programming entity that enables an
> escape from the normal XAML processor handling of string attribute
> values or object elements, and defers the processing to a backing
> class. T**he character that identifies a markup extension to a XAML
> processor when using attribute syntax is the opening curly brace (`{`),
> followed by any character other than a closing curly brace (`}`)**. The
> first string following the opening curly brace must reference the
> class that provides the particular extension behavior, where the
> reference may omit the substring "Extension" if that substring is part
> of the true class name. Thereafter, a single space may appear, and
> then each succeeding character is used as input by the extension
> implementation, up until the closing curly brace is encountered.

More information here

[Overview of markup extensions for XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/markup-extensions-overview)

Also another good link tendered by [@Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface)

[Basic Markup Extension Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/markup-extensions-and-wpf-xaml?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#basic-markup-extension-syntax)

> A markup extension can be implemented to provide values for properties
> in an attribute usage, properties in a property element usage, or
> both.
>
> When used to provide an attribute value, the syntax that distinguishes
> a markup extension sequence to a XAML processor is the presence of the
> opening and closing curly braces ({ and }). The type of markup
> extension is then identified by the string token immediately following
> the opening curly brace.
>
> When used in property element syntax, a markup extension is visually
> the same as any other element used to provide a property element
> value: a XAML element declaration that references the markup extension
> class as an element, enclosed within angle brackets (<>).

Comment: Ok so I read that page already. It's.... well, it's hot garbage. They couldn't have made it more obscure if they tried. It's like trying to read a spec document. _"The first string following the opening curly brace must reference the class that provides the particular extension behavior, where the reference may omit the substring "Extension" if that substring is part of the true class name."_ Wtf. I have no clue what that means. I'm not new to programming and I can't understand it, so how is anyone that's _actually_ new supposed to figure this out? It boggles the mind.

Comment: @Clonkex I feel your pain, and understand your frustration.

Comment: This might be a better link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/markup-extensions-and-wpf-xaml?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#basic-markup-extension-syntax

Comment: It is just like attributes. You can say [KeyAttribute] or [Key] and they both target class KeyAttribute. However, if you define a KeyAttributeAttribute, then the first one will preferable bind to it.